# append every new time into list

Tags: python-3.x, list, time

How can I append new time into a list?

```
import time

time_status = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
time_list = []
while True:
    time_list.append(time_status)
    print(time_list)
    time.sleep(59)
```

Output should be:

```
['17:48:50','17:48:51','17:48:52','17:48:53']
```

Comment: How do you want to end the loop? Also, the output is too regular and predictable for any time range to do any eager waitiing.

Comment: just hit Ctrl+C

Comment: Can't you just wait for user input and build the list at the end. Or do you need that snapshot every second?

Comment: I need that snapshot every second.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you have to update `time_status` *within* the loop. Then you should wait for a little less than a second not to do too much eager waiting:

```
import time

time_list, crnt = [], None
while True:
    while (time_status := time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) == crnt:
        pass
    time_list.append(crnt := time_status)
    print(time_list)
    time.sleep(0.95)

['11:36:40']
['11:36:40', '11:36:41']
['11:36:40', '11:36:41', '11:36:42']
['11:36:40', '11:36:41', '11:36:42', '11:36:43']
['11:36:40', '11:36:41', '11:36:42', '11:36:43', '11:36:44']
```